# How to make vertical bar in equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations

When I try this:

```
\begin{equation}
    \overline{bel}(x_{t}) = p (  x_{t}  \textbar z_{1:t-1} , u_{1:t} )
\end{equation}
```

I get following warning:

> Command \textbar invalid in math mode on input line 12.

I aim to produce following output:
 [image]

What should I do ?

Comment: Not sure of what you want to obtaim, but why not `\bar`?

Comment: I want to write this equation without any warning ! Sorry I don't understand what do you mean (but why not \bar) ?

Comment: Is `bel` supposed to be a function?

Comment: It works now by deleting \textbar and write | .

Comment: Try with `\mid` instead.

Comment: Perfect \mid makes space in both sides, thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply typing `|` should be completely sufficient:

```
\begin{equation}
    \overline{bel}(x_{t}) = p (  x_{t} | z_{1:t-1} , u_{1:t} )
\end{equation}
```

If you show us what the result is supposed to be, we can maybe help a little more.

Please, also provide a MWE (minimum working example, that is a complete file with preamble and only what is actually needed).

Comment: Probably `\mid` would have a  better spacing.

Comment: @Bernard - could you post that as an answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score -1):

use `\text{\textbar}` (*amsmath* package is needed)

Comment: Using a text symbol for a mathematical operator is never a good idea.  `\mid` is really the best alternative here.